# What is the difference between a money order and a money judgment?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, legal-terms

Presumably there is some distinction as it is made in the name of the so called register of orders fines and judgments. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

In American English, a "money order" is a low dollar value cashier's check issued by a non-bank institution in most cases, while a "money judgment" is a court determination that someone owes money to a judgment creditor that authorizes the use of involuntary means to collect the debt. But, it appears that "money order" has a different meaning in British English.

Comment: Yes exactly this is asking in the sense of the British context.

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

They are similar in that they both say what a debtor must pay to a creditor and the deadline for payment.

A 'money order' is a type of court order.

Sometimes other types of court orders, e.g. 'possession orders', have a 'money judgement' attached to them.

A money order counts as a county court judgment (CCJ) and can therefore affect the debtor's credit rating.

A money judgement does not count as a CCJ.

In both cases, the creditor must return to court for enforcement if the debtor continues to fail to pay.